# Ubuntu 14.04 on Amazon EC2- postfix segmentation fault

Tags: amazon-ec2, postfix, email-server, ubuntu-14.04, segmentation-fault

I have an EC2 instance using Ubuntu 14.04 which is where I want to send email from.
I tested it by sending an email:

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line " myemailid@gmail.com
```

But it gave me an error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I checked `/var/log/syslog` and found this:

```
Sep 25 09:26:47 my-server-hostname kernel: [321695.640722] mail[7863]: segfault at c0 ip 00007f58c4d5318e sp 00007ffdfc146f90 error 4 in libmailutils.so.4.0.0[7f58c4ccf000+a9000]
```

What should i do to fix this?

I don't know if this is relevant to this question, but I used a dynamic DNS address from [duckdns](https://www.duckdns.org/) and during the postfix setup,

I entered `"mydomainname.duckdns.org"` in the `'System mail name'` field.

Comment: Can you check permissions for /tmp directory. is it publicly writable?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your error messages show the segmentation fault is **not** happening in Postfix, but in the `mail` command, more precisely in the shared library `libmailutils.so` which it uses.

Normally a segmentation fault indicates a software bug and the next step would be either to report the problem to the program author or to run the program in a debugger to find out exactly where the fault is happening. But the `mail` program is so widely used that such a bug seems improbable, and I'd rather suspect a damaged binary file.

Consequently, as a first step I'd recommend to reinstall both the `mail` command and the `libmailutils.so` shared library to see if the error goes away. Also check if the system is current on updates.

Comment: Reinstalled, still getting the same error

Comment: Did you reboot the server? Sometimes stale copies of shared libraries remain in memory after an update.

Comment: Restarted and tried again, still getting a segfault..

Comment: Strange. If you have some idea of programming you might try getting a backtrace from the core dump with `gdb` and/or to run the `mail` command under `strace` to get an idea where and why it is dying. Otherwise I fear your only option is to report a bug to Ubuntu.

Comment: Hmm... i have programming experience,but not with C/C++ and linux....i think i'll just report the bug...

Comment: Also, i was browsing around for other ways to send email, and i found the 'sendmail' command and that seems to work!! Does sendmail work with mailutils or is it completely different? If i just want to use sendmail, can i uninstall the mailutils package?

Comment: The `sendmail` command is indeed completely different. In your case, since you installed `postfix` it is part of the `postfix` package. (There's an alternative mail server package called `sendmail`, too, which would of course bring its own version of the `sendmail` command, but you won't want that.) So you can uninstall the `mailutils` package if you don't need it for anything else.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same error while switching to root user & this [link](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3461191)  helped me to address the issue.

Actually there were some changes made to root’s bash profile `“/root/.bashrc”` and i reverted the changes as mentioned in above link.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.